# why does this happen in the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am gonna print numbers less than 5, but the answer is not what I mean? how should I solve the problem?

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for b in a:
 if b>=5:
  a.remove(b)      
print(a)
```

answer:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345424/in-place-modification-of-array-in-python basically don't modify array's that you are iterating over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)